# MITM Attack on Key Exchange Protocols

Tags: rsa, public-key, diffie-hellman, chosen-plaintext-attack, man-in-the-middle

I was doing research on this attack and I am wondering, why is Diffie-Hellman always

associated with such an attack? ​ Aren't other public key cryptography schemes vulnerable

to the same kind of attack? ​ To be more specific, is RSA vulnerable to such an attack?

If so, which versions and how can they be carried out?

Comment: Sure, any scheme that doesn't authenticate at least one party is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. This works with DH style key exchange and with key transport mechanisms where the attacker just supplies his own public key instead of the real one.

Comment: Well i would believe it is often associated with Diffie-Hellman, since DH uses purely the direct communication channel between the users to generate a private key while RSA uses (publicly available) precomputed keys.
But as SEJPM said, except for quatum-cryptography, any scheme is vulnerable...